# Using Wildcard in query criteria when referencing form input

Tags: vba, ms-access, wildcard

I am attempting to use a form to initiate and return query results based on user selected criteria (via a series of 24 combo boxes).  So, if the user selects from a drop down, the subform requeries and returns results from query with the selected value as a filter.  I need the user to be able to select as many or as few criteria as desired.  I have that piece working using the following:

In the query that populates the subform, each criteria has:
`Like "*" & [Forms]![formname]![cobx_name] & "*"`

Like I said, this works.  The problem lies in one of the criteria.  There is a field that contains a sequential numeric value (from 1 to over 11,000).  When I select, say 7, the query returns records with numerical value 7, 17, 27, 37, and so on.  I need for the query to use wildcard and return all records when that specific combo box is null, but return only the one record that is equal to the value (i.e. just the record with value 7 for example) that the user selected.

Comment: there is an * in the statement...the editor must have ignored them...so there are * in between the quotation marks in the Like statement.

Comment: LIKE and wildcard is intended for text data, not numbers. I never use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Format code as code in question and * shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE and wildcard is intended for text not numbers. If you must use dynamic parameterized query, consider this:

`BETWEEN Nz([Forms]![formname]![cobx_name], 0) AND Nz([Forms]![formname]![cobx_name], 99999)`

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  The values are numbers but the field is short text data type.

Comment: June7, THANK YOU.  That worked perfectly and allows all other combo box criteria to remain working as intended too.  Really appreciate the help!

Comment: If answer resolves issue could mark as accepted and upvote would be nice as well. Why is field text type?

Comment: The numerical value in this field is an unique ID within the original data set.  It will never require any calculation of any kind, and therefore ingested into the database as text.  I did accept the answer and did vote up, but it says that my reputation level is not high enough to change the publicly displayed post score.  But it said that the vote is recorded.  I'll have to work to get my reputation up to at least 15 to vote effectively.  Thank you again for your assistance on this!